# How to pass a list of custom object records from Apex to Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

EDIT: Updated Apex controller

I want to pass custom object records to a vf page to be rendered as a table. See below code. The controller method is called from a LWC.

Apex Controller:

```
public List<Transaction__c> getTransactions() {
    String transactionIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('transactions');
    String formattedString = transactionIds.remove(')');
    String formattedString2 = transactionIds.remove('(');
    List<String> idList = formattedString2.split(',');
    List<Transaction__c> transList = [SELECT Id, Amount__c FROM Transaction__c
    WHERE Id IN :idList];
    return transList;
}

@AuraEnabled 
public static String getPdfFileAsBase64String(List<Id> transactionIds) {
    PageReference pdfPage = Page.TransactionStatement;
    pdfPage.getParameters().put('transactions', transactionIds.toString());
    Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();
    String base64Pdf = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob);
    return base64Pdf;
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="PrintJobPDFController" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" readOnly="true">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Transactions">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.transactions}" var="trans">
         <apex:column value="{!trans.Amount__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I'm sure I need to do something other than `transactions.toString()` in the controller but I'm not sure what. Currently I get an error `Unknown property 'String.Amount__c'`. I have tried with a VF page looking like this but I just get a blank table:

```
<apex:page controller="PrintJobPDFController" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" readOnly="true">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Transactions">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!transactions}" var="trans">
         <apex:column value="{!trans.Amount__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The URL parameter `transactions` is a singleton String but you are trying to interpret it as a collection of SObjects in the VF page. You'll need the controller property `transactions`'s getter to fetch the URL value and construct a list of sobjects for this to work. Don't fetch the URL param in the page.

Comment: Thanks, I now have `public List<Transaction__c> getTransactions() {
        String transactionIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('transactions');
        List<String> idList = transactionIds.split(',');
        List<Transaction__c> transList = [SELECT Id FROM Transaction__c
        WHERE Id IN :idList];
        return transList;
    }` but it still doesn't seem to be returning anything

Comment: please use [edit] and amend your code to what you now have; too hard to interpret code in comments.

Comment: thanks, have done this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that `transactionIds` had whitespace on each element so when split into `List<String>` each element looked like `"  a0O25000007doLmEAI"`. Once I removed the whitespace it worked.

PrintJobPDFController :

```
public with sharing class PrintJobPDFController {

    public List<Transaction__c> getTransactions() {
        String transactionIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('transactions');
        String formattedString = transactionIds.deleteWhiteSpace();
        List<String> idList = formattedString3.split(',');

        List<Transaction__c> transList = [SELECT Id, Amount__c FROM Transaction__c
        WHERE Id IN :idList];
        return transList;
    }

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String getPdfFileAsBase64String(List<Id> transactionIds) {
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.TransactionStatement;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('transactions', transactionIds.toString());
        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();
        String base64Pdf = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob);
        return base64Pdf;
    }
}
```

TransactionStatement.page:

```
<apex:page controller="PrintJobPDFController" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" readOnly="true">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Transactions">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!transactions}" var="trans">
         <apex:column value="{!trans.Amount__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```